# Excel data export fixing number errors/removing green triangles

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, office-interop, office-2007

After exporting data using a third party component the data in the excel sheet isn't type correctly. Excel thinks that some values are string while they are numbers and a little green triangle shows up.

We've coded the following to fix this:

```
For Each objCell As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range In objWorkSheetReport.Range(objWorkSheetReport.Cells(1, 1), objWorkSheetReport.Cells(Me.RowCount + 10, Columns.Count + 10)).Cells
    If IsNumeric(objCell.Value) Then
        objCell.Value = CDbl(objCell.Value)
    End If
Next
```

This removes all those little green triangles but is really slow.

**The question**

Is there a faster way to convert a Range of data quickly so the green triangles don't show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.SpecialCells()` method of the range to narrow it down to only those cells that need to be changed.

Assuming a range `NarrowedRange` and a worksheet `Sheet` (substitute your own range for `A1:A8`, and `objWorksheetReport` for your sheet)

```
NarrowedRange = 
    Sheet.Range("A1:A8").SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants,
                                      Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues)
```

will get you only the text value elements of your original range, so just change those accordingly.

Comment: This is still a really slow operation. Isn't there any way to speed it up?

Comment: @Coding Do you have the sheet open when you are doing the operation?  It would speed it up if you just let the engine do the work in the background.  If you must have it open, turn off [ScreenUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating(v=office.11).aspx).  How many rows do you have?  I figured the `SpecialCells` would speed it up a tad, so I wish that had performed better.  All else fails, set up a question on [Programmer's](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) about optimizing these type of operations.